# SQL Query - why does this return no results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

If I run this T-SQL query, I get 25 records with results in all 3 fields

```
SELECT *
FROM Data.Results
WHERE
CONTAINS (IndividualName, 'Titan') OR
CONTAINS (EntityName, 'Titan') OR
CONTAINS ([Text], 'Titan')
```

However if I run this, I get zero results.

```
SELECT *
FROM Data.Results
WHERE
CONTAINS (IndividualName, 'The AND Titan AND Group AND Inc') OR
CONTAINS (EntityName, 'The AND Titan AND Group AND Inc') OR
CONTAINS ([Text], 'The AND Titan AND Group AND Inc')
```

But with the first query, most of my results *do* include "The Titan Group Inc" in the fields.

I run these kinds of CONTAINS queries all day with no issues. This particular one is the only one giving me trouble. Am I missing something glaringly obvious in the 2nd query?

Comment: `' "The" AND "Titan" AND "Group" AND "Inc" '`

Comment: Note that [noise words](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142551(v=sql.90).aspx), e.g. "the", are ignored.

Comment: @juergen d: I use hundreds of these CONTAINS queries with AND every day.  That is not the issue.  This is the syntax we use for all of our queries and we need the AND's in there to account for the possibility of the words being in different order, or, certain words not being included at all.

Comment: @scsimon: still doesn't work.

Comment: @HABO: thanks, agreed on "the."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Full-Text-Search returns no results when any noise words are in search string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3113519/sql-full-text-search-returns-no-results-when-any-noise-words-are-in-search-strin)